# Optimize Prestashop in Docker

Tags: php, docker, symfony, docker-compose, prestashop

I want to configure proper dev environment for Prestashop 1.7 using Docker.
Issue is that it's quite slow. Profiler(from Symfony) shows around 2.7-6 seconds to load some admin pages. (freshly installed website). In production we have website working not in docker container and page load speed is around 150-250ms. I understand that it might be slow because of some large folders like "vendor",  so I tried some ways to optimize it by adding :delegated. Performance probably was improved for several seconds, but still 3 seconds is not comfortable to work. I would like to improve it at least to load within 1000ms.

Prestashop image from: https://hub.docker.com/r/prestashop/prestashop/

You can try this docker-compose to play around what can be modified to improve:

```
version: '3'

services:
  prestashop:
    build: ./docker/prestashop
    container_name: app
    ports:
      - 80:80
    links:
      - mariadb:mariadb
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    volumes:
      - ./docker/common:/scripts
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
      - vendor:/var/www/html/vendor
      - var:/var/www/html/var
    environment:
      - PS_DOMAIN=localhost
      - PS_DEV_MODE=1
      - DB_SERVER=mariadb
      - DB_USER=root
      - DB_PASSWD=root
      - DB_NAME=ps_test
      - PS_INSTALL_AUTO=1
      - PS_COUNTRY=EE
      - ADMIN_MAIL=test@prestashop.ee
      - ADMIN_PASSWD=test123
      - PS_INSTALL_DB=1

  mariadb:
    build: ./docker/mariadb
    container_name: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=ps_test
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/mariadb/logs/:/var/log/mysql:delegated

volumes:
  db_data:
  vendor:
  var:
```

prestashop Dockerfile:

```
FROM prestashop/prestashop:1.7-7.2-apache

RUN yes | pecl install xdebug \
    && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=off" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_port=9000" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "file_uploads=On" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini \
    && echo "memory_limit=1G" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini \
    && echo "upload_max_filesize=64M" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini \
    && echo "post_max_size=64M" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini \
    && echo "max_execution_time=600" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini \
    && echo "max_input_vars=100000" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini \
    && echo "error_reporting-1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini \
    && echo "display_errors = On" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
RUN chown 1000 /var/www -R
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which OS do you use, but I had performance issues working with a Docker PrestaShop install on Windows. I changed to Linux and it's way better now.

Comment: Had this issue when using Docker on a Mac due to poor filesystem performance with application using many small files.... Had an acceptable improvement by switching to VIRTIOFS as described here: https://www.docker.com/blog/speed-boost-achievement-unlocked-on-docker-desktop-4-6-for-mac/

Comment: @gennaris did you find any fix for Mac?